# How can I diagnose hardware NIC problems in Linux?

Tags: linux, network-interface, debugging

I have one Dell PowerEdge R640 out of 22 losing packets regularly (once every about 3 minutes). I have checked:

- the cable (used a different cable still the same behavior)
- the switches and all the networking configs (no errors)
- the local networking configs (again no errors, bond is up)
- dmesg | grep "Error\|Warning" (no errors)
- I have updated the OS (RHVH 4.3)
- I have updated the networking firmware to Dell QLogic 15.00.14

The funny things is I have a 4x 10Gbps NIC with the first two ports in a bond and they both loose packets on an about 3 minutes working, 1 minute losing packets interval.

But the other two ports on the NIC (3 & 4) don't loose any packets at all.

T̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶m̶ ̶g̶o̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶w̶i̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶N̶I̶C̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶s̶, but I find it very weird that there is no evidence of the faulty NIC in any of the linux logs.

What else could I try? Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

LE: Switched the NICs and the same server has the same problem even with another NIC and the server that I put the presumed bad NIC in looses no packets. I'm starting to think this is a motherboard problem.

Comment: Longshot comment, do you have any duplicate MAC addresses on premises? While exceedingly rare, this might cause intermittent packet losses. Since you are checking things, I would rule this out.

Comment: I've checked the mac address table of the switch, no duplicate macs. Duplicate mac addreses cause a different type of loss, a couple of packets go through then a couple drop and repeat.